# Dropdown..... Ondeselct EvetTrigger Is not Working properly in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, drop-down-menu, textmeshpro

I am using the Event Trigger for my game For the Dropdown Selection and deselect.
But When The Dropdown is open and I click on the Empty space the Dropdown Closed but the Event trigger on Deselect is Not working properly.
Is there any way to do that.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: not sure but is it possible that your Dropdown actually stays selected until you actually select a different UI element?

Comment: There Are 2 things
1- when I click on the dropdown and click on the one of the Option's of the dropdown, the dropdown closes and selection is made.
2- when I click on the dropdown the dropdown open's and when I click on empty area the dropdown closes with the selection currently highlighted in dropdown.